# Blocos vs Funções em Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Qual é a diferença entre blocos e funções em Objective-C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O bloco é uma "função anônima", que você atribui a uma variável e/ou passa adiante como parâmetro. Como a função não tem nome, só pode usá-la quem possui uma referência direta.

Exemplo tirado da documentação da Apple: (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1)

```
int (^myBlock)(int) = ^(int num) {
    return num * multiplier;
};
```

O bloco é semelhante ao code block do Ruby, ao function () do Javascript, Também é semelhante ao closure presente em muitas linguagens, mas com limitações.

O bloco é interessante quando é preciso passar um callback ao Cocoa. Muitas vezes este callback é curtinho, e é burocrático criar mais um método ou função só para passá-lo adiante.

Situação bastante comum em animações. Exemplo tirado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292044/putting-a-fade-in-fadeout-effect-on-objective-c

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        // fade out effect
        _self.myView.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL success){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            // fade in effect
            _self.myView.alpha = 1.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL success){
            // recursively fire a new animation
            if (_self.fadeInOutBlock)
                _self.fadeInOutBlock();
        }];
    }];
```